# Freemarker: Removing Items from One Sequence from Another Sequence

Tags: sequence, freemarker

This may be something really simple, but I couldn't figure it out and been trying to find an example online to no avail.  I'm basically trying to remove items found in one sequence from another sequence.

**Example #1**

Items added to the cart is in one sequence; items removed from cart is in another sequence:

<#assign Added_Items_to_Cart = "AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE,FFFF">

<#assign Deleted_Items_from_Cart = "BBBB,DDDD">

The result I'm looking for is: AAAA,CCCC,EEEE,FFFF

**Example #2**

What if the all items added to and deleted from cart are in the same sequence?

<#assign Cart_Activity = "AAAA,BBBB,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE,DDDD,FFFF,Add,Add,Delete,Add,Add,Add,Delete,Add">

The result I'm looking for is the same: AAAA,CCCC,EEEE,FFFF

Answer (score 0):

**First things first:** You ask about sequence but the data you are dealing with are strings.

I know you are using the string to work as a sequence (and it works), but sequences are sequences and strings are strings, and they have diferente ways of dealing with. I just felt this was important to clarify if someone who is starting to learn how to program get to this answer.

**Some assumptions since you're providing strings with data separated by comma:**

- You want a string with data separated by comma as a result.
- You know how to properly create strings with data separated by comma.
- You dont have commas in your items names.

**Observations:**

- I'll give you the logic but not the code donne, as this can be a great chance for you to learn/practice freemarker (stackoverflow spirit, you know...)
- You question is not about something specific of freemaker (it just happens to be the language you want to work with). Think about adding the **logic** tag to you question. :-)

**Now to the answer on how to do what you want on a "string that is working as a sequence":**

**Example #1**
Change your string to a real sequence :-)

1 - Use a [built-in to split your string on commas](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_split). Do it for both *Added_Items_to_Cart* and *Deleted_Items_from_Cart*. Now you have two real sequences to work with.

2 - Create a new string tha twill be your result .

3 - [Iterate over the sequence](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref.directive.list) of added itens.

4 - For each item of the added list, you will [check if the deleted list also contains](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_contains) this item.

4.1 - If the deleted list contains the item you do nothing.

4.2 - If the deleted list **do not** contains the item, you add that item to your string result

At the end of this nested iteration (thats another hint) you should get the result you're looking for.

**Example #2**
There are many ways of doing it and i'll just share the one that pops out of my mind right now.

I think it's noteworthy that in this approach you will always have an even sized list, as you always insert 2 infos each time: item and action.
So always the first half will be the 'item list' and the second half will be the 'action list'.

1 - [Change that string to a sequence](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_split) (yes, like on the other example).

2 - Get half of [its size](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_size) (in your example size = 16 so half of it is 8)

3 - Iterate over a [range](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_direct_ranges) from *0* to *half-1* (in your example 0 to 7)

4 - At each iteration you'll have a number. Lets call it **num** (yes I'm very creative):

4.1 - If at the position **num + half** you have the word "Add" you add the item of position **num** in your result string

4.2 - If at the position **num + half** you have the word "Delete" you remove the item of position **num** from your result string

**And for the grand finale, some really usefull links that will help you in your freemarker life forever!!!**

All built-ins from freemarker:
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins.html

All directives from freemarker:
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_alphaidx.html

Freemarekr cheatsheet :
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#exp_cheatsheet